# Type-casts problematic in libSVM?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, svm, libsvm

I have a very simple 'issue' with [LibSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/):

I am on a Mac, OSX, 10.9.5. I cloned the libSVM repo from [here](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/), and as per the instructions on the [README](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/blob/master/README), simply ran `make`.

This is *supposed* to compile the libSVM programs without issue, but I am getting a litany of warnings about signedness.

Needless to say, this concerns me, because of signs are changing willy nilly, I will have no faith in the classifier. Should this be something of concern, and if so, how do I go about resolving it?

Here is what I get when I run the `make` command from the command line:

```
adam-MacBook-Pro:libsvm adam$ make
c++ -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -fPIC -c svm.cpp
svm.cpp:96:26: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-conversion]
        head = (head_t *)calloc(l,sizeof(head_t));      // initialized to 0
                         ~~~~~~ ^
svm.cpp:98:10: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-conversion]
        size -= l * sizeof(head_t) / sizeof(Qfloat);
                ^ ~
svm.cpp:146:54: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-conversion]
                h->data = (Qfloat *)realloc(h->data,sizeof(Qfloat)*len);
                                                                  ~^~~
svm.cpp:1651:38: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'const int' to 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-conversion]
        double *alpha = Malloc(double,prob->l);
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
svm.cpp:39:40: note: expanded from macro 'Malloc'
#define Malloc(type,n) (type *)malloc((n)*sizeof(type))
                                       ^
svm.cpp:1722:26: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-conversion]
        double *t=Malloc(double,l);
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
svm.cpp:39:40: note: expanded from macro 'Malloc'
#define Malloc(type,n) (type *)malloc((n)*sizeof(type))
                                       ^
svm.cpp:1833:29: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-conversion]
```

Comment: If you trust the lib, ignore it, or report the problem.

Comment: @2501 Hi, the problem is that I am just beginning to use it for medical data classification, so I do not know how trust-worthy the library is. Seeing as how it is quite popular, I am inclined to suspect the problem is in the way it is being compiled?

Comment: Warnings seem pretty clear to me, someone ignored conversions, or knew( assumed ) the values can't be negative.

Comment: @lejlot Hi Lejlot, I saw that you have some experience with libSVM, and I would value any insight you can give for this small problem here. Thanks!

Comment: @2501 FWIW, the original author tells me over email "It works on linux so it should be fine" (??). Not sure what that means exactly. Isnt that a compilation issue?